# Override res/values/strings.xml file with /strings.xml download to sd card from server android

Tags: android

I want to replace `strings.xml` file which is embedded into the `apk`, by a `strings.xml` file downloaded from server and stored into my internal `sd card`. Is it possible to reference external tags to `TextView`. My clients want to have complete control over languages in the application.  If i successfully download `strings.xml` from server and stored it to sd card, how can i reference the tag element to respective `TextViews`. I don't really need code but only ideas and critism about this method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will work because your resources get compiled into the apk in a special way so that they can be accessed based on the device configuration. This happens at compile time. You can't simply swap out the strings.xml later while the app is installed.

Comment: if we extend textview and put our downloaded strings.xml into it can we reference it

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. If you want to achieve this, you will have to set the language in runtime while creating your controls.

If you have complete layouts (not creating dynamic controls), you will have to recursively scan your layouts, looking for buttons, textviews, hints etc., recognize the control and set the text property from the downloaded file.

something like this:

put your language in a hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, String> LANG = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and set the tag property for each of your controls in your layout. Then you can find them like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<yourLayout.getChildsCount;i++)
{
    View v = yourLayout.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof Button){
        ((Buttons)v).setText(LANG.get(v.getTag()));
    }
}
```