# Changing language without using miltiple XML files in the project

Tags: android, xml, multilingual

Every time when developing a multiple language app:

> By default android considers English as primary language and loads the string resources from `res/values/strings.xml`. When you want to add support for another language, you need to create a values folder by appending a hyphen and the ISO language code. For example if you want to add support for French, you should create a values folder named `values-fr` and keep a `strings.xml` file in it with all the strings translated into French language.

(http://web.archive.org/web/20140725004322/http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/)

### My Question:

Is there any way to develop a multi-language app without following the above procedure?

### My Requirement:

For all the respective languages..there are corresponding XML files in server and i have to use them and  translate the language.

Comment: Your app depends on server and not operational without server, right?

Comment: Yup...I followed this procedure..Taking global static variables in a java class and when ever user selects language the code will be redirected to a server and using xml parser i will parse the data and will the get the required data from the server and will update in my global variables and with this global variables values i will replace with the strings.xml values

Comment: If your server has all the languages' XMLs then why do you need to have it in your app? I guess you could just send the language code to server and it should send data back in that requested language.

Comment: have XML files on server? that contains string resources?

Comment: yup i am having all the xml files in the server @ Darpan

Comment: @santoshkaradla check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23335851/1276636) answer. It may help you.

Comment: the main problem i am facing is when ever i am exiting the app,all the global variables data is taking their default values and the changed language values were gone..code: logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
   }
  });

Comment: Then, while initiating your `Application` class and fetch the xml. read it and save the corrosponding values in a hashmap. Get the values one by one whenever you wish to post them.

Comment: save those global variable in something more persistent, like sharedPreference?

Comment: I am having around 200 global variables...is it possible to store all those variables in shared preferences

Comment: @santoshkaradla how are you caching? Can you list few global variables being used?

Comment: Just by using static variables..default value {   public static String RESTORE = "Restore";}  changed value {Strings.RESTORE = parser.getElementByID("MENU_RESTORE");}

Comment: Have you checked the link I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795012/changing-language-without-using-miltiple-xml-files-in-the-project?noredirect=1#comment42165230_26795012)? I think it should help keep things easy (especially when you have it to `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion.. I am working on Shared Preferences Only Right now..when it woks i will definitely update here the sequence which i have followed..@Sufian...